# Can I use Trait Doctoring to to make a Circle of Protection monocolor or multicolor?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Can [Trait Doctoring](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Trait%20Doctoring) be used to change a Circle of Protection (whatever color) into protection from mono or multicolor? [Trait Doctoring](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Trait%20Doctoring) reads

> Change the text of target permanent by replacing all instances of one color word with another or one basic land type with another until end of turn.
>
> Cipher *(Then you may exile this spell card encoded on a creature you control. Whenever that creature deals combat damage to a player, its controller may cast a copy of the encoded card without paying its mana cost.)*

Do monocolor and multicolor count as "color words"? I sort of assumed so but I'm not really sure.

Comment: related: http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/12927/3128

Comment: I've never heard of the color "multicolor". It's definitely not one of the 5 in MTG!

Comment: Note that Trait Doctoring + Circle of Protection is effectively a nonbo: the overwhelming majority of damage coming your way doesn't happen *on your own turn*. That's a lot of work just to make a really lousy [Personal Sanctuary](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=220235). If you really want to play customize-your-own-CoP, use a card like [Alter Reality](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=34832) or [Glamerdye](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=153439).

Comment: But why would you need multicolor anyway? You can just say part of the multicolor you would like to block.

Answer (score 11):

No, it cannot.

As per the ruling on [the card](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=369034):

> The type-changing effect can change part of a word such as “nonblack” or “swampwalk” if the part of the word is being used to refer to **a color** or basic land type.

Referring to color in general does not refer to *a color*.

As per the comp rules:

> 105.1. There are five colors in the *Magic* game: white, blue, black, red, and green.
>
> 105.4. If a player is asked to choose a color, he or she must choose one of the five colors. "Multicolored" is not a color. Neither is "colorless."